# Column size checks in EDM?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I've noticed that EF 4.3 does not have checks on column sizes. Going through the feature list of EF5 learned me that I have to come up with my own solution. Some other ORM's I've looked at also lack this behaviour.

Before I start hardcoding these checks in my service layer I wanted to know how most of you handle this.

Am I to lazy as a programmer or do more of you consider this as a shortcoming?

Comment: Have you tried using StringLengthAttribute/MaxLengthAttribute? Built-in validation should kick in and validate the length of the value against the value set in the attributes. You can also set max length values using fluent API.

Comment: Something important I did not mention is that my classes are automatically generated. Looks my best option in a database first approach is to use StringLength/MaxLength annotations on the properties in my metadataclasses.

Comment: I would at least have expected a 1 on 1 datatype check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a (complete) mapping between datatypes in EF, you will not find it. Best to come up with is to add checks to your poco's and keep them in sync or build some fancy errorhandling.